# POST request with a JSON object that contains a File

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, file-upload

I have a JSON object like so:

```
const people = {
  admin: {
    name: 'john',
    avatar: {
      img: File
    }
  },
  moderator: {
    name: 'jake',
    avatar: {
      img: File
    }
  }
};
```

The `img` property is just a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object.

---

## What I want to do

I want to send this data as a `POST` request to my node server.

---

## What I've tried:

So one approach that seems to work is to create a `FormData` object and then manually append each property to it like so:

**client.js**

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('admin-name', people.admin.name);
formData.append('admin-avatar', people.admin.avatar.img);
formData.append('moderator-name', people.moderator.name);
formData.append('moderator-avatar', people.moderator.avatar.img);

fetch('/submit', { method: 'POST', body: formData })
```

**server.js**

```
import formidable from 'express-formidable';

router.use('/submit', formidable());

router.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files); // This contains the Files objects
  console.log(req.fields); // This has the rest of the data
  res.end();
});
```

**Server Output**

```
{ 'admin-avatar': File {}, 'moderator-avatar': File {} }
{ 'admin-name': 'john', 'moderator-name': 'jake' }
```

---

## The problem with this approach

The main reason I don't like doing it this way is because I have to manually `append` every single field. I don't think I can do this in a loop because in my data, some of the fields are nested objects. Also, in my server, the data is no longer grouped together like it was in the original object.

Is there any better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any clean/elegant way of dynamically creating a `FormData` object. You could solve the repetitiveness by looping over the properties with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
const people = {
  admin: {
    name: 'john',
    avatar: {
      img: {}
    }
  },
  moderator: {
    name: 'jake',
    avatar: {
      img: {}
    }
  }
}

const formData = new FormData()

Object.keys(people)
  .forEach(authority => {
    const { name, avatar: img } = people[authority]
    formData.append(`${authority}-name`, name)
    formData.append(`${authority}-avatar`, img)
  })
```

Comment: Sorry, my example could have been improved, but in my actual data the `admin` and `moderator` might have some different fields, in which case I don't think something like this could work. If there isn't a good way of creating a `FormData` object for this, is there some other approach that could work?

Comment: If the shape of your object is dynamic, then I don't think there really is a way. The solution above would work if you know for sure some common properties on your object.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, gave you an upvote. I guess I'm just confused on how people normally handle this? I feel like submitting a form which also takes in a file input must be pretty common, so I just felt like there had to be a better way than to manually do every field.